# How do I update table column with random values between 18 to 100

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I had a table tblCustomers with CustomerID, Name,Email, and PhoneNumber Columns. 
I just added a column AGE which has null values by doing the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tblCustomers
ADD Age int;
```

I would like to populate this column records with ages between 0 to 100. How do I do it the right way.

P.s. I looked up online and found this

```
UPDATE tblCustomers
SET    Age = abs(checksum(NewId())) % 100
WHERE  Age IS NULL
```

Are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: So just random numbers as age? Why?

Comment: `RAND` function maybe?

Comment: In support of @Ean's post, by default the `RAND` function assigns a random value if no value is passed (aka if field is null). This sounds about right for your specific scenario. [See MSFT TN Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx)

Comment: I just realized that `RAND` doesn't fit your requirement. Which version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: Your solution is fine if you want a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblCustomers
SET    Age = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) % 100 
WHERE  Age IS NULL
```